# Apache is failing to start after enabling/disabling mod_ssl

Tags: ssl, proxy, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

4.7 (Ubuntu) and I tried to setup a proxy with SSL on already existing instance that acts as proxy for other non-ssl apps. I enabled ssl by running a2enmod ssl and restarted. Instantly I received alerts that proxies for other apps stopped working. Immediately I ran a2dismod ssl command and restarted apache which failed. In apache2/error.log i found the following errors:

Mon Aug 17 23:04:31.670430 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16151:tid 140301083379584] AH02241: Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/ssl/touc.com.pem
[Mon Aug 17 23:04:31.670473 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16151:tid 140301083379584] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Aug 17 23:04:31.670491 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16151:tid 140301083379584] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=X509)
[Mon Aug 17 23:04:31.670501 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 16151:tid 140301083379584] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.

Since then I am not able to make other proxies available, but when I access their URLs directly they are working. Any clues what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what exactly went wrong. Apparently enabling ssl_mod disables proxy_http and when you disable ssl_mod you need to re-enable proxy_http. As soon as you restart your apache server everything works.